# Reference to global functor in another global functor

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code yields a `Segmentation Fault` on the `y = anotherFunctor()` line. As far as I understand, this happens because the `globalFunctor` variable does not exist when `anotherFunctor` is created. But why does it work if I replace `std::function<int(int)>` with `GlobalFunctor`? How would I fix it?

```
#include <functional>

struct GlobalFunctor
{
    int operator()() const { return 42; }
};
extern GlobalFunctor globalFunctor;

struct AnotherFunctor
{
    AnotherFunctor() : g_(globalFunctor) {}

    int operator()() const { return g_(); }

    const std::function<int()>& g_;
} anotherFunctor;

GlobalFunctor globalFunctor;

int main()
{
    AnotherFunctor af;
    int x = af();
    int y = anotherFunctor();
    int z = x + y;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I tried compiling this with `clang` instead of `gcc` and it warns me about `binding reference member 'g_' to a temporary value` -- but it crashes when compiling this. Would the cast to `std::function` create a temporary reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `g_(globalFunctor)`, `globalFunctor` has to be converted to an `std::function` because it is of type `GlobalFunctor`. So a temporary is produced and this is bound to the constant reference. You could think of the code as doing `g_(std::function<int()>(globalFunctor))`. However, this temporary only lives until the end of the constructor, as there is a special rule in C++ saying that temporaries in member initializer lists only live until the end of the constructor. This leaves you with a dangling reference.

The code works when you replace `std::function<int(int)>` with `GlobalFunctor` because no conversion is involved. Therefore, no temporaries are produced and the reference directly refers to the global object.

You either need to not use references and store a `std::function` internally or make a global `std::function` and have a reference to that.